# Eclipse MarkerAnnotation with actions

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, annotations, hover, eclipse-pde

I'm creating an Eclipse (Juno) plugin which displays data to the user when hovering over marked lines.
I'm creating an IMarker, then create a MarkerAnnotation from the marker and add it to the IAnnotationModel.

I'm displaying it on the existing (generic) editor and did not create a custom one.

All this works great, but I need to add actions to the annotation, something like the Javadoc links, so clicking an ID in the annotation text, would run an action.

This is not quick fix, because the links should be embedded inside the text.

How can I do that? Didn't find any solution which didn't require creating custom source viewer.

Thanks.

Update: tried hyperlink detector, but it looks like it can't be used on marker annotations, only on text editors.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to implement a [marker resolution processor](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_ui_ide_markerResolution.html?cp=2_1_1_160). That calculates possible actions to resolve markers (like "add TODO", "delete line"). Those possible resolutions are shown by Eclipse when hovering over markers or when using Ctrl-1 (quick assist) on a marker.

Besides that, you may want to have a look at the [hyperlink detector extension point](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_ui_workbench_texteditor_hyperlinkDetectors.html). That one creates clickable links in the text, when pressing Ctrl (e.g. hover over a method call in the Java editor, press Ctrl and that method call becomes clickable).

Comment: Thank you Bananeweizen. I don't think marker resolution processor will fit the process I'm implementing, but I will look into hyperlink detector.

Comment: I've tried hyperlink detector, but it looks like I can't use it on marker annotations, only on text editors. Am I missing something?